# How can I repeat the header but not the caption with longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable

I am trying to set up a `longtable` where the header is repeated on every new page but the caption only appears once at the top of the page.

The table is defined as follows:

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption{the table caption} \label{tab:11swpkg}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}
HeaderCol1 & HeaderCol2 & HeaderCol3\endhead    
\hline\hline
Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

This nearly works because the header is indeed repeated after a page break but so is the caption. How can I get rid of the caption after a page break?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look for `\endfirsthead` in the manual of `longtable`

Comment: With `texdoc longtable` you can read the very good documentation of package `longtable`.  On page 4 f you can find what you are searching for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is given as a model for getting you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[textheight=2in]{geometry} %% Just to make textheight smaller

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption{the table caption} \label{tab:11swpkg}\\
\hline
%
\rowcolor{gray}
HeaderCol1 & HeaderCol2 & HeaderCol3\\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline
\rowcolor{gray}
HeaderCol1 & HeaderCol2 & HeaderCol3\\
\hline\hline
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
%
\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline
\endlastfoot
%
Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). It need only one compilation to get the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=2in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}  

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{Continued from previous page}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {The Table Caption},
  label = {tab:11swpkg},
]{colspec={lll},rowhead=1,row{1}={gray9}}
\toprule
HeaderCol1 & HeaderCol2 & HeaderCol3 \\
\midrule
  Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
  Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
  Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
  Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
  Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
  Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\hline
  Item11 & Item12 & Item13 \\
\hline
  Item21 & Item22 & Item23 \\
\hline
  Item31 & Item32 & Item33 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]