# Longtable same header, different caption

Tags: longtable

The standard use case for `longtable` must be as follows:

- Headers on every page
- Caption on the first page
- Table *x*: Continued... on each subsequent page

So why does this seem so hard to do? [This SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71612/31839) suggests that the right way to do this is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{My favourite caption}\label{tbl:table}\\
    \toprule
                  & foo \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
\caption{Continued...}\\
    \toprule
                  & foo \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    bar           & 1 \\
    baz           & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

But this seems to me to be a seriously flawed workflow. If I notice a typo in the column headers (and there may be *many* column headers!) I have to fix it in *two different places*!

Is there really no way to achieve what seems to me to be the completely standard use case without breaking [this pretty fundamental rule of coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter Considered. Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You do have a macro processor to hand....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{%
    \toprule
                  & foo \\
    \midrule}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{My favourite caption}\label{tbl:table}\\
\foo
    \endfirsthead
\caption{Continued...}\\
\foo
    \endhead
    bar           & 1 \\
    baz           & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a sensible way to go. But I think the world is divided into those who use `\newcommand` pretty much constantly, and those (like me, sadly) who are too scared to even get started with it. I always think that if a package requires `\newcommand` to work as expected, the package needs an overhaul.

Comment: @LondonRob it's not that the _package_ requires it, it's an author command, If you need to type any set of words or commands more than once you are free to make a macro so you only need it once. That's nothing to do with longtable, same applies to subterms of equations, common technical phrases in your subject area, anything really.

Comment: True, @DavidCarlisle, but I suppose that my objection is to the extremely common nature of the use case. Basically everyone who uses `longtable` will want to do some variant on this, so it should be baked in.

Comment: @LondonRob I disagree (and it's my code so I win:-) It would mean implementing and documenting some kind of macro replacement system specific for this case in the general macro language of tex which seems odd. You can't just say "duplicate the header" as the non duplicated parts (the caption, the label, the continued....) might appear at the top or botom or middle of the header code so you'd have to implement and document positional options which is more complicated to implement and more complicated for the user who may be expected to be familiar with `\newcommand`

Comment: Wow! Didn't know I was talking to the developer! Maybe just some documentation that makes this use case as clear as day. Keep up the good work.