# Show table caption only on first page

Tags: captions, longtable, labels

I have a `\longtable` that splits over two pages and currently shows the label and caption at the top of each page. Can I change this so that the caption and label to only appear on the first page and still keep the headers on each page?

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}||p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \caption{Some text}
    \label{tab:1}
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}  & \textbf{Definition}  \endhead
    \hline
    ...                                              
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: change `\endhead` to `\endfirsthead` (and possibly also have an `\endhead` with the headings without the caption.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71549/how-can-i-repeat-the-header-but-not-the-caption-with-longtable?rq=1) as a basis, I changed my table to this:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}||p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:1}
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Definition}  \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Definition}  \endhead
    \hline
    ...
\end{longtable}
```